# How do I fix the Smart UV Unwrap zooming in to the texture on my model?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

Im trying to combine multiple material slots into one image texture by baking the materials onto a new image texture but I ran into an issue while unwrapping.

[image]

[image]

How do I unwrap this correctly and combine the materials into one single texture for my asset library?